# Linux cannot find -lboost_zlib

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to build a C++ program under Linux (it was originally developed under Windows), during which I am asked to install `cmake` and `libboost`.

I installed both. But I am still getting an error message

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_zlib
```

The question is where can I find `libboost_zlib`. Perhaps this program was supposed not to be runnable under Linux?

I already installed `libboost-all-dev`, and I found there is nothing like `libboost_zlib` in the library.  Thanks for your time!

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but did you see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937723/compiling-boost-with-zlib

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion! Yeah, I am trying to figure out the example posted in the link. However, situation is quite different between Windows and Linux :(

Comment: `locate libboost_zlib`, take note of the directory, and add `-L/path/to/libboost_zlib_folder` to your compilation/linking

Comment: Thanks, but the `locate libboost_zlib` returns empty ...

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I figured out the problem. The`libboost_zlib`is no long existed in the new `libboost` distribution(at least after version 1.46). Instead, `zlib` is integrated in `libboost_iostreams`. So there is no need to link `libboost_zlib`, `libboost_iostreams` does all the work.

Comment: > libboost_iostreams does all the work.

Nope, it does not. You still have to link your target executable with zlib somehow