# Compiling boost with zlib on windows

Tags: c++, boost, zlib, boost-iostreams

Is there is good tutorial on how to compile boost with zlib on windows. 
I looked over boost reference, but it's vague and not enough.
I did download zlib dll and source code and made reference in visual studio. 
I have link error on

```
gzip_decompressor();
```

complete code:

```
using namespace boost::iostreams;
using namespace std;
std::ifstream file("hello.gz", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
filtering_streambuf < input > in;
in.push(gzip_decompressor());
in.push(file);
boost::iostreams::copy(in, std::cout);
```

I am getting this error,

> Error 11 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "_declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall
>   boost::iostreams::detail::gzip_header::~gzip_header(void)"
>   (__imp??1gzip_header@detail@iostreams@boost@@QAE@XZ) referenced in
>   function "public: __thiscall
>   boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor
>   \>::~basic_gzip_decompressor >(void)" (??1?$basic_gzip_decompressor@V?$allocator@D@std@@@iostreams@boost@@QAE@XZ)
>   –

Comment: You will have to be more explicit and provide the exact link errors that you are getting. Note that you have to explicitly link with zlib and boost_iostreams, ie add them and the paths to the project settings. (Let me know if this works for you so I can expand it to an answer.)

Comment: Error 11 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::gzip_header::~gzip_header(void)" (__imp_??1gzip_header@detail@iostreams@boost@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_gzip_decompressor<class std::allocator<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_gzip_decompressor@V?$allocator@D@std@@@iostreams@boost@@QAE@XZ)

Comment: Looking at your linking error and repeating my first comment - have you in fact added the boost_iostreams library to the linker inputs of your VS project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linker actually tells you that it cannot find the "basic_gzip_decompressor". The reason is because you have zlib *not* built into your boost libraries.

([This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12497515/4823151) claims to have a solution *without* having to build zlib into boost libs)

I agree that the documentation on this is a bit terse, but it is [found here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/iostreams/doc/installation.html). If your normal build commandline is like this:

```
b2 -j15 --toolset=msvc --build-type=complete stage
```

add the ZLIB definitions to make it build with zlib

```
b2 -j15 --toolset=msvc --build-type=complete stage -s ZLIB_SOURCE="C:\zlib-1.2.8" -s ZLIB_INCLUDE="C:\zlib-1.2.8"
```

you can relatively quickly check whether it works (before compilation is complete) when you look for the configuration check output. There it should say something like:

```
- zlib               : yes  (cached)
```

Comment: Seems not enough

Comment: For the 1.63 Boost with the Intel compiler in 64-bit mode on Windows, I use a second `-s` in front of the ZLIB_INCLUDE like so: `-s ZLIB_INCLUDE=C:\YourPath\To\The\ZlibRootDir\ `, and then it compiles without saying how zlib.cpp cannot open zlib.h