# Build boost with zlib support linked dynamically

Tags: c++, boost, dll, zlib

I have troubles with building boost libraries.

I am using version 1.55 on OS Win7.

According to [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/iostreams/doc/installation.html#bjam) and another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937723/compiling-boost-with-zlib) I found switches that work to build boost with zlib support.

I haven't found a way, how to build boost (static or dynamic) libraries with zlib being external dependency, and will be shipped with my application. In that way, any user can build/change his own zlib, as long as the interface is unchanged.

I such thing possible? Does boost support dynamic zlib linkage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve the problem with the following.

There is a [bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9156) in versions 1.55 and above. Building static libraries can be done using older jamfile (1.53).

For the dynamic library, you need to add zlib.cpp to your project and compile.
With dynamic, meaning there is only zlib.dll linked directly to your project.