# Boost not finding zlib package on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boost, build, zlib, b2

I'm trying to compile Boost with the zlib package built into Ubuntu, but it cannot find it and thus gives me a `zlib : no` upon running `./b2`.
I definitely have it installed, as `dpkg -L zlib1g-dev` and `dpkg -L zlib1g` give me their locations.
I've tried manually passing in the directories as command-line options as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9077570/7736506), and I've also tried creating a `user-config.jam` file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66061954/7736506), but nothing has worked.
Any ideas as to what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For unclear reasons, the solution was just to get rid of everything in the Boost directory and recompile + reinstall Boost. After that it was able to find zlib (and bzip2) without any problems.